# "Categories" on my front page

Tags: categories

I just switched to Wordpress and i want to delete (or hide) the "Categories" section that comes up in my main page. is it possible?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely, I believe this article might help you https://blog.templatetoaster.com/how-to-remove-page-title-wordpress/